# If two coils have different lengths, then while calculating mutual Inductance, which length is to be considered - shorter one or longer one?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, inductance, electromagnetic-induction

When we derive the mutual inductance formula, the area of the inner loop is taken. But what about length? If two coils have different lengths, then while calculating mutual Inductance, which length is to be considered - shorter one or longer one?

Answer (score 1):

Think of them as individual loops and add them to get the resultant.

Answer (score 1):

If the changing current in coil 1 makes the emf induced in coil 2, then the length of coil 1 is to be considered while calculating mutual inductance.